# The topology on $\mathbb{R}$ when the open sets are $\{U\subset \mathbb{R}: 0 \notin U\} \cup \{\mathbb{R}\}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification

I am working on a problem which I do not have an answer.

If the topology on $\mathbb{R}$ is defined when the open sets are
$$
\{U\subset \mathbb{R}: 0 \notin U\} \cup \{\mathbb{R}\}
$$
then is this topological space:

1. Hausdorff?

I don't think so because for origin, the only open set covering it is $\mathbb{R}$, then for any nonzero point in $\mathbb{R}$ and any open set covering it, you cannot make these two open sets disjoint.

2. Connected?

I don't think so for almost the same reason as for Hausdorff. If you have two non empty disjoint open sets, then one of it must be $\mathbb{R}$, contradiction.

3. Compact?

I think it is because if you have $\mathbb R$ be covered, one of these open sets in the covering must be $\mathbb R$, then the finite subcovering is exactly $\mathbb R$.

Thanks in advance for pointing out my mistake if any.

## Update

The topology is connected. I misremembered the definition of the connectedness.

Comment: You showed it is connected.....

Comment: Everything else looks right

Comment: Another question you might want to consider: Is it path connected?

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp thanks for your advice! I don't think it is path connected. If it is there exists some continuous function f maps zero to some point x.Then the inverse image of the neighborhood of x must contain zero so the inverse image must be $\mathbb R$ which means f is constant which leads to contradiction.

Comment: @MasamiNagasawa No, you proved that it is connected (by contradiction). Check the definition of connectedness.

Comment: @mathworker21 thank you so much! I found it

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp yeah, I found that

Comment: If this were an exam Q then for 2. I would say that if $A$ and $B$ are open and $A \cup B =\mathbb R$ then $(0\in A\lor 0\in B)$, therefore  $(A=\mathbb R\lor B=\mathbb R),$ which implies connectedness.